# Html5boilerplate build script not updating SRC attribute

Tags: html5boilerplate, build-script

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316098/how-to-configure-html5boilerplate-build-script-to-get-script-src-attributes-repl but I'm not using a php prefix and it happens both to CSS and JS

In my original html I have

```
<!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- end CSS-->
```

and

```
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts -->
```

After I build successfully, the css and js folder have a new minified concatenated and renamed .css and .js files but the html have the same src=""s just without the comments.

Even worse, the modernizr-2.0.6.min.js file is not copied to the publish folder which should be since it's not concatenated to the eg fe30b2e.js file (since it's in the header and the rest of js at the end)

The publish/css folder has a a109b0e.css minified file and a copy of the original style.css file which doesn't seem right.

I'm using the latest version of the build script (I'm guessing that clicking the ZIP button in GitHub downloads the latest version) and OS X 10.6.8

UPDATE: I tried running the build script against a clean and just downloaded versions of the boilerplate and the same happens, the src attributes don't update so I guess there is a bug in the build script.